# How to stop jquery datatable sortcut search?

Tags: jquery, datatables

Like if we type p from keyboard then it remove pagination table from datatable. Similary if there is search box above all column but we type s from keyboard then it make focus on Main search box  of datatable

Comment: So, simply you need to apply this functionality using button click

Comment: Jquery datatable provide builtin function i.e, set "data-key-event:false" where you set the property for the table.

Comment: @SD please add your code so by this way you will help the community